# Buildozer Error

Tags: android, python, buildozer

I tried to create a Kivy APK using Buildozer but I keep receiving the same error no matter what I do. I am using Ubuntu. Here is the Error:

```
[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 172):
jnius/jnius.c:47655:20: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 

'signed size_t', but argument 4 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=] 
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate':    
jnius/jnius.c:47902:7: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=] 
       dtype->name, (Py_ssize_t)dtype->size, (dtype->size > 1) ? "s" : ""); 
       ^    
jnius/jnius.c:47902:7: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but argument 6 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]   
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_ValidateAndInit_memviewslice':    
jnius/jnius.c:51148:22: warning: format '%zu' expects argument of type 'size_t', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=]   
                      (dtype->size > 1) ? "s" : "");    
                      ^ 
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__pyx_f_5jnius_5jnius_convert_python_to_jobject':   
jnius/jnius.c:11068:21: warning: '__pyx_v_retmidinit' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]    
   __pyx_v_retobject = (__pyx_v_j_env[0])->NewObjectA(__pyx_v_j_env, __pyx_v_retclass, __pyx_v_retmidinit, __pyx_v_j_ret);  
                     ^  
jnius/jnius.c:11068:21: warning: '__pyx_v_retclass' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]  
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius   
/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android Python Development/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/tools/liblink.sh --sysroot /home/perrythekeypad/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -lm -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/libs_collections/myapp/armeabi-v7a -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/libs_collections/myapp/armeabi-v7a -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/libs_collections/myapp -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2_gradle-python2/obj/local/armeabi-v7a -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -I/home/perrythekeypad/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -isysroot /home/perrythekeypad/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -I/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python2.7 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.o -Llibs/armeabi-v7a -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi-v7a/python2/python-install/lib -lSDL2 -llog -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.so  
unable to execute /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android: Permission denied 
error: command '/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android' failed with exit status 1
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a/pyjnius && /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host setup.py build_ext -v

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android Python Development/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 172):
    jnius/jnius.c:47655:20: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but argument 4 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]  
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate':    
jnius/jnius.c:47902:7: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=] 
       dtype->name, (Py_ssize_t)dtype->size, (dtype->size > 1) ? "s" : ""); 
       ^    
jnius/jnius.c:47902:7: warning: format '%zd' expects argument of type 'signed size_t', but argument 6 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]   
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_ValidateAndInit_memviewslice':    
jnius/jnius.c:51148:22: warning: format '%zu' expects argument of type 'size_t', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat=]   
                      (dtype->size > 1) ? "s" : "");    
                      ^ 
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__pyx_f_5jnius_5jnius_convert_python_to_jobject':   
jnius/jnius.c:11068:21: warning: '__pyx_v_retmidinit' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]    
   __pyx_v_retobject = (__pyx_v_j_env[0])->NewObjectA(__pyx_v_j_env, __pyx_v_retclass, __pyx_v_retmidinit, __pyx_v_j_ret);  
                     ^  
jnius/jnius.c:11068:21: warning: '__pyx_v_retclass' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]  
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius   
/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android Python Development/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/tools/liblink.sh --sysroot /home/perrythekeypad/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -lm -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/libs_collections/myapp/armeabi-v7a -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/libs_collections/myapp/armeabi-v7a -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/libs_collections/myapp -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2_gradle-python2/obj/local/armeabi-v7a -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -I/home/perrythekeypad/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -isysroot /home/perrythekeypad/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -I/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python2.7 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.o -Llibs/armeabi-v7a -L/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi-v7a/python2/python-install/lib -lSDL2 -llog -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.so  
unable to execute /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android: Permission denied 
error: command '/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android' failed with exit status 1
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a/pyjnius && /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host setup.py build_ext -v

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android Python Development/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I am not sure what keeps causing this error.
I tried this command in the terminal:

```
buildozer android debug
```

It keeps failing to run command:

```
/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp
--bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android Python Development/.buildozer/android/platform/build
```

Comment: `unable to execute /home/perrythekeypad/Documents/Android: Permission denied` - you need to make sure the permissions for this directory are correct (and possibly, that it exists).